# Lots of failures on my logs

Tags: nginx

I am seeing the bellow record on my log file every two seconds.
I am using nginx on centos 7.

```
2021/03/16 13:59:21 [error] 8904#8904: dvcasha2.ocsp-certum.com could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out) while requesting certificate status, responder: dvcasha2.ocsp-certum.com, certificate: "/etc/nginx/ssl.crt/bundle.crt"
```

I don't know what is it.
Is it something I should worry ?

Comment: You have a certificate whose revocation status cannot be checked.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

You have likely missed DNS resolver configuration from your nginx configuration.

You can try adding:

```
resolver <ns1> <ns2>;
```

in your `http` configuration level. `<ns1>` and `<ns2>` are your name server IP addresses, you can find them in `/etc/resolv.conf`.